# Matching html input values with regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to match a string like the following:

```
<input type="text" value="cbyEOS56RK3lOxtiCrhmWSkDuNWwrFN4" name="iden">
```

This is my code:

```
$pattern = '~value="(.+?)" name="iden"~';
preg_match($pattern, $page, $match);
print_r($match);
```

As you can probably see, I am trying to match the value in this HTML input. By what I know of regular expressions, `.*` will match as many characters as possible until it satisfies the next token (in this case `"`).

I have the `name="iden"` part in my regex because there are other HTML inputs on the page and I only want to match this one.

Problem is, I'm not getting any matches at all. `$match` is an empty array. And I know that `$page` has the right content because I can see it when I echo it.

Help fixing my regex is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This regex works fine when I test it. Are you sure that the content $page doesn't have any extra white space that your regex is not accounting for (newlines, tabs, extra spaces between attributes, etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the phrase "there are other inputs on the page", I assume you're trying to parse out this particular tag from a full HTML document. In that case, I recommend using a [DOM parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+html+dom+parser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) rather than regular expressions (I'm not trying to be facetious with that link, there's just a lot of options so that seemed easiest). They are designed specifically for this purpose and will be a lot easier in the end.

If you want to try regex anyway, I would personally use `([^"]+)` instead of `(.+?)`:

```
$pattern = '~value="([^"]+)" name="iden"~';
```

Though this still doesn't address whatever is causing your problem, as your regex should match on that line.

Comment: I don't fully agree with tihs. Depending on the task, a full-fledged DOM parser might well be overkill. A simple regex is often the best tool for a task like this.

Comment: @Ben Lee: The DOM parser would more elegantly handle the arbitrary whitespace/newlines/etc that you refer to in your previous comment, though. If this was as simple as the question appears initially, then his regex ought to work, no?

Comment: Good point. Agreed that a DOM parser is generally better if you're the whitespace is variable (a regex to account for optional whitespace everywhere can get really ugly).

Comment: @Ben Lee: Yup, that's pretty much all I was getting at. If it really is "I need to match this line" then it should work, so I'm guessing it's something else...